# How many zeros are there in $1 \times 2^2 \times 3^3 \times \cdots \times 100^{100}$?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

How many zeros are there at the end of $1 \times 2^2 \times 3^3 \times \cdots \times 100^{100}$ ?

I tried it by grouping all the $2$'s and $5$'s and $5$'s and $6$'s but cant get my answer...

Comment: **Hint**: Since the largest power of 5 dividing your result has a much smaller exponent than the largest power of 2, you can ignore every factor except the ones of the form $(5k)^{5k}$.

Comment: Looks like a [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/) challenge ... in fact, I am pretty sure I have done a challenge like this on project euler or [spoj.com](http://www.spoj.com/).

Answer (score 9):

Hint: The number of 5's is $(5 + 10 + 15 + \ldots + 95 + 100) + (25 + 50 + 75 + 100)$.

Comment: cannot get it....

Comment: Also note MJD's hint. What did you try?

Comment: i cannot understand the number of 5's hint...

Comment: All numbers of the form $5n$ contain 5 and numbers of the form $25n$ contain two 5's. There are non numbers containing three 5's, since $5^3 = 125 > 100$.

Comment: Typo: "... are no numbers ..."

Answer (score 9):

To get a zero you need to multiply a factor $5$ by a factor $2$. There are clearly more factors of $2$ than of $5$ in the product, so you need to find a systematic way of counting the factors of 5.

Well these come from the terms $5^5\cdot 10^{10} \cdot 15^{15} \dots 100^{100}$

All of these terms provide a factor $5$ so we have $5^5\cdot 5^{10} \cdot 5^{15} \dots 5^{100}$, with exponent $5+10+15+ \dots +100$.

However the multiples of $25$ contribute twice, and we've only counted them once so far, so we need to add $25+50+75+100$ to the exponent.

We have no multiples of $5^3=125$ which would have contributed three factors.

The exponent counts the number of factors of $5$ and hence the number of zeros.

Comment: Nice explanation Mark Bennet.....

Answer (score 0):

I checked the product using  "PARI GP " program and found both the previous answers to be correct.
The total number of zeroes =(5+10+15+...+95+100) +(25+50+75+100) =5*10*21+250=1300